# django-q and azure app service. Unable to start backend process in azure app service

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-appservice

I am using django application for my web based application, now to implement async functionality I am using django q package.
Using this I have put some functionality behind the user interface and it is working locally.

But once code is deployed into the azure app service (Linux plan) it is not working. It is not working because as part of Django-q we have to run the cluster in the backend. It looks like this python manage.py qcluster

As I am not able to start the background process in-app service this specific functionality is not working. I have tried to add the custom startup command in app service but nothing is working out.

Tried creating a custom shell script and placed it in the /home directory but that is also not working and tried calling the script from startup command but not working.

Note :- The application is being deployed to app service via azure devops pipelines.

Thanks for your help.
[image: App service custom command]

Answer (score 1):

In the root of your project include a startup.sh file, this file will include all of the startup commands that you want to run. It it possible to put your commands directly into the "startup command" section of your Azure web app but this is not recommend. To run qcluster you would do something like:

```
python manage.py qcluster &
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 <your app>.wsgi --access-logfile '-' --error-logfile '-'
```

On your azure web app set the startup command to: `startup.sh`

After deploying these changes you can validate that you new startup script is being called by looking at `/opt/startup/startup.sh`. For a more robust approach you might want to consider running qcluster as a systemd service

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-04